# Windows 10 not directly bootable from Grub anymore (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

I have used a dual boot system with Windows since 4.10 (Warty) and aside from Windows, after a fresh installation, regularly overwriting Grub, all has worked fine so far.

However since monday (17.09.2018) I am unable to boot to my Windows 10 installation from Grub directly. The entry is still there, but when I select it and press Enter it just shows the Grub menu again.

Strangely if I press 'c' to get to a terminal and then type 'exit', the system boots into my Windows installation successfully. This means Windows is still bootable.

Booting to my Ubuntu 18.04 installation works perfectly as it used to.

This also is no duplicate of [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix). It did not occur after installing Ubuntu and the fix proposed in that thread does not work, but rather does the new boot entry show the exact same behaviour. Here is the output from the bootinfoscript, if that is of any use:
[Link to Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/e9amgUrX)

> ```
> Boot Info Script 0.61      [1 April 2012]
>
>
> ============================= Boot Info Summary: ==============================
>
> => Grub2 (v1.99) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of 
> the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
> in partition 114 for .
> => Grub2 (v1.99) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb and looks at sector 1 of 
> the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
> in partition 135 for .
> => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdc.
>
> sda1: __________________________________________________________________________
>
> File system:       ntfs
> Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
> Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
> Operating System:  
> Boot files:        
>
> sda2: __________________________________________________________________________
>
> File system:       ext4
> Boot sector type:  -
> Boot sector info: 
> Operating System:  
> Boot files:        
>
> sdb2: __________________________________________________________________________
>
> File system:       ext4
> Boot sector type:  -
> Boot sector info: 
> Operating System:  Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
> Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab
>
> sdb3: __________________________________________________________________________
>
> File system:       swap
> Boot sector type:  -
> Boot sector info: 
>
> sdc1: __________________________________________________________________________
>
> File system:       ntfs
> Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
> Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
> Operating System:  
> Boot files:        
>
> sdc2: __________________________________________________________________________
>
> File system:       vfat
> Boot sector type:  Unknown
> Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
> Operating System:  
> Boot files:        /efi/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi /efi/Boot/bootx64.efi 
>                    /efi/Boot/fbx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/fwupx64.efi 
>                    /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi 
>                    /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi
>
> sdc3: __________________________________________________________________________
>
> File system:       
> Boot sector type:  -
> Boot sector info: 
> Mounting failed:   mount: /tmp/BootInfo-LqSMQMp2/sdc3: unbekannter Dateisystemtyp „“.
>
> sdc4: __________________________________________________________________________
>
> File system:       ntfs
> Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
> Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
> Operating System:  
> Boot files:        /bootmgr /Windows/System32/winload.exe
>
> ============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================
>
>  Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________
> Festplatte /dev/sda: 931,5 GiB, 1000204886016 Bytes, 1953525168 Sektoren
>  Einheiten: Sektoren von 1 * 512 = 512 Bytes
>  Sektorgröße (logisch/physikalisch): 512 Bytes / 4096 Bytes
>  E/A-Größe (minimal/optimal): 4096 Bytes / 4096 Bytes
>  Festplattenbezeichnungstyp: dos
>
> Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System
>
> /dev/sda1             206,848 1,024,002,047 1,023,795,200   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
> /dev/sda2       1,024,002,048 1,953,523,711   929,521,664  83 Linux
>
>
> Drive: sdb _____________________________________________________________________
> Festplatte /dev/sdb: 111,8 GiB, 120034123776 Bytes, 234441648 Sektoren
> Einheiten: Sektoren von 1 * 512 = 512 Bytes
> Sektorgröße (logisch/physikalisch): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes
> E/A-Größe (minimal/optimal): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes
> Festplattenbezeichnungstyp: dos
>
> Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System
>
> /dev/sdb2    *          2,048   190,767,103   190,765,056  83 Linux
> /dev/sdb3         190,767,104   234,440,703    43,673,600  82 Linux swap / Solaris
>
>
> Drive: sdc _____________________________________________________________________
> Festplatte /dev/sdc: 465,8 GiB, 500107862016 Bytes, 976773168 Sektoren
> Einheiten: Sektoren von 1 * 512 = 512 Bytes
> Sektorgröße (logisch/physikalisch): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes
> E/A-Größe (minimal/optimal): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes
> Festplattenbezeichnungstyp: gpt
>
> Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System
>
> /dev/sdc1                   1 4,294,967,295 4,294,967,295  ee GPT
>
> /dev/sdc1 ends after the last sector of /dev/sdc
>
> GUID Partition Table detected.
>
> Partition    Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors System
> /dev/sdc1           2,048       923,647       921,600 Windows Recovery Environment (Windows)
> /dev/sdc2         923,648     1,128,447       204,800 EFI System partition
> /dev/sdc3       1,128,448     1,161,215        32,768 Microsoft Reserved Partition (Windows)
> /dev/sdc4       1,161,216   976,773,119   975,611,904 Data partition (Windows/Linux)
>
> "blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________
>
> Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL
>
> /dev/loop0                                              squashfs   
> /dev/loop1                                              squashfs   
> /dev/loop10                                             squashfs   
> /dev/loop11                                             squashfs   
> /dev/loop12                                             squashfs   
> /dev/loop13                                             squashfs   
> /dev/loop14                                             squashfs   
> /dev/loop15                                             squashfs   
> /dev/loop16                                             squashfs   
> /dev/loop17                                             squashfs   
> /dev/loop18                                             squashfs   
> /dev/loop19                                             squashfs   
> /dev/loop2                                              squashfs   
> /dev/loop20                                             squashfs   
> /dev/loop21                                             squashfs   
> /dev/loop22                                             squashfs   
> /dev/loop23                                             squashfs   
> /dev/loop24                                             squashfs   
> /dev/loop3                                              squashfs   
> /dev/loop4                                              squashfs   
> /dev/loop5                                              squashfs   
> /dev/loop6                                              squashfs   
> /dev/loop7                                              squashfs   
> /dev/loop8                                              squashfs   
> /dev/loop9                                              squashfs   
> /dev/sda1        3C088A7C088A3544                       ntfs       Daten
> /dev/sda2        e365b6b6-cbd2-42f3-84d5-e0fff42416f5   ext4       
> /dev/sdb2        1b4c1f8c-da20-43e8-aafe-8726f047c11f   ext4       
> /dev/sdb3        24c324b4-3b2e-4d15-8d71-9150d1729d35   swap       
> /dev/sdc1        342E4A592E4A13F0                       ntfs       
> /dev/sdc2        54A7-D57B                              vfat       
> /dev/sdc3                                                          
> /dev/sdc4        3096B53196B4F884                       ntfs       
>
> ================================ Mount points: =================================
>
> Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options
>
> /dev/sda2        /home                    ext4       (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
> /dev/sdb2        /                        ext4       (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
> /dev/sdc2        /boot/efi                vfat       (rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
>
>
> =========================== sdb2/boot/grub/grub.cfg: ===========================
>
>     --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> #
> # DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
> #
> # It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
> # from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
> #
>
>  ### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
> if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
>   set have_grubenv=true
>   load_env
> fi
> if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
>    set default="${next_entry}"
>    set next_entry=
>    save_env next_entry
>    set boot_once=true
> else
>    set default="0"
> fi
>
> if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
>   menuentry_id_option="--id"
> else
>   menuentry_id_option=""
> fi
>
> export menuentry_id_option
>
> if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
>   set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
>   save_env saved_entry
>   set prev_saved_entry=
>   save_env prev_saved_entry
>   set boot_once=true
> fi
>
> function savedefault {
>   if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
>     saved_entry="${chosen}"
>     save_env saved_entry
>   fi
> }
> function recordfail {
>   set recordfail=1
>   if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
> }
> function load_video {
>   if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
>     insmod all_video
>   else
>     insmod efi_gop
>     insmod efi_uga
>     insmod ieee1275_fb
>     insmod vbe
>     insmod vga
>     insmod video_bochs
>     insmod video_cirrus
>   fi
> }
>
> if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
>    font=unicode
> else
> insmod part_msdos
> insmod ext2
> set root='hd1,msdos2'
> if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
>   search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,msdos2 --hint-efi=hd1,msdos2 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,msdos2  1b4c1f8c-da20-43e8-aafe-8726f047c11f
> else
>   search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 1b4c1f8c-da20-43e8-aafe-8726f047c11f
> fi
>     font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
> fi
>
> if loadfont $font ; then
>   set gfxmode=auto
>   load_video
>   insmod gfxterm
>   set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
>   set lang=de_DE
>   insmod gettext
> fi
> terminal_output gfxterm
> if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
>   set timeout=30
> else
>   if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
>     set timeout_style=hidden
>     set timeout=10
>   # Fallback hidden-timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
>   # unavailable.
>   elif sleep --interruptible 10 ; then
>     set timeout=0
>   fi
> fi
> ### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
>
>  ### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
> set menu_color_normal=white/black
> set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
> if background_color 44,0,30,0; then
>   clear
> fi
> ### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
>
>  ### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
> function gfxmode {
>     set gfxpayload="${1}"
>     if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
>         set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=1
>     else
>         set vt_handoff=
>     fi
> }
> if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
>   if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
>     if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
>       if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
>         set linux_gfx_mode=keep
>       else
>         set linux_gfx_mode=text
>       fi
>     else
>       set linux_gfx_mode=text
>     fi
>   else
>     set linux_gfx_mode=keep
>   fi
> else
>   set linux_gfx_mode=text
> fi
> export linux_gfx_mode
> menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-1b4c1f8c-da20-43e8-aafe-8726f047c11f' {
>     recordfail
>     load_video
>     gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
>     insmod gzio
>     if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
>     insmod part_msdos
>     insmod ext2
>     set root='hd1,msdos2'
>     if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
>       search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,msdos2 --hint-efi=hd1,msdos2 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,msdos2  1b4c1f8c-da20-43e8-aafe-8726f047c11f
>     else
>       search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 1b4c1f8c-da20-43e8-aafe-8726f047c11f
>     fi
>         linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-34-generic root=UUID=1b4c1f8c-da20-43e8-aafe-8726f047c11f ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
>     initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-34-generic
> }
> submenu 'Erweiterte Optionen für Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-1b4c1f8c-da20-43e8-aafe-8726f047c11f' {
>     menuentry 'Ubuntu, mit Linux 4.15.0-34-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.15.0-34-generic-advanced-1b4c1f8c-da20-43e8-aafe-8726f047c11f' {
>         recordfail
>         load_video
>         gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
>         insmod gzio
>         if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
>         insmod part_msdos
>         insmod ext2
>         set root='hd1,msdos2'
>         if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
>           search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,msdos2 --hint-efi=hd1,msdos2 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,msdos2  1b4c1f8c-da20-43e8-aafe-8726f047c11f
>         else
>           search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 1b4c1f8c-da20-43e8-aafe-8726f047c11f
>         fi
>         echo    'Linux 4.15.0-34-generic wird geladen …'
>             linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-34-generic root=UUID=1b4c1f8c-da20-43e8-aafe-8726f047c11f ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
>         echo    'Initiale Ramdisk wird geladen …'
>         initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-34-generic
>     }
>     menuentry 'Ubuntu, mit Linux 4.15.0-34-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.15.0-34-generic-recovery-1b4c1f8c-da20-43e8-aafe-8726f047c11f' {
>         recordfail
>         load_video
>         insmod gzio
>         if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
>         insmod part_msdos
>         insmod ext2
>         set root='hd1,msdos2'
>         if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
>           search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,msdos2 --hint-efi=hd1,msdos2 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,msdos2  1b4c1f8c-da20-43e8-aafe-8726f047c11f
>         else
>           search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 1b4c1f8c-da20-43e8-aafe-8726f047c11f
>         fi
>         echo    'Linux 4.15.0-34-generic wird geladen …'
>             linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-34-generic root=UUID=1b4c1f8c-da20-43e8-aafe-8726f047c11f ro recovery nomodeset 
>         echo    'Initiale Ramdisk wird geladen …'
>         initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-34-generic
>     }
>     menuentry 'Ubuntu, mit Linux 4.15.0-33-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.15.0-33-generic-advanced-1b4c1f8c-da20-43e8-aafe-8726f047c11f' {
>         recordfail
>         load_video
>         gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
>         insmod gzio
>         if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
>         insmod part_msdos
>         insmod ext2
>         set root='hd1,msdos2'
>         if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
>           search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,msdos2 --hint-efi=hd1,msdos2 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,msdos2  1b4c1f8c-da20-43e8-aafe-8726f047c11f
>         else
>           search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 1b4c1f8c-da20-43e8-aafe-8726f047c11f
>         fi
>         echo    'Linux 4.15.0-33-generic wird geladen …'
>             linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-33-generic root=UUID=1b4c1f8c-da20-43e8-aafe-8726f047c11f ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
>         echo    'Initiale Ramdisk wird geladen …'
>         initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-33-generic
>     }
>     menuentry 'Ubuntu, mit Linux 4.15.0-33-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.15.0-33-generic-recovery-1b4c1f8c-da20-43e8-aafe-8726f047c11f' {
>         recordfail
>         load_video
>         insmod gzio
>         if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
>         insmod part_msdos
>         insmod ext2
>         set root='hd1,msdos2'
>         if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
>           search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,msdos2 --hint-efi=hd1,msdos2 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,msdos2  1b4c1f8c-da20-43e8-aafe-8726f047c11f
>         else
>           search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 1b4c1f8c-da20-43e8-aafe-8726f047c11f
>         fi
>         echo    'Linux 4.15.0-33-generic wird geladen …'
>             linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-33-generic root=UUID=1b4c1f8c-da20-43e8-aafe-8726f047c11f ro recovery nomodeset 
>         echo    'Initiale Ramdisk wird geladen …'
>         initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-33-generic
>     }
> }
>
> ### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
>
> ### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###
>
> ### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###
>
> ### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/25_custom ###
>
> menuentry "Windows UEFI bootmgfw.efi" {
> search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root 54A7-D57B
> chainloader (${root})/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
> }
>
>  menuentry "Windows Boot UEFI loader" {
> search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root 54A7-D57B
> chainloader (${root})/EFI/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
> }
>
>  menuentry "EFI/ubuntu/MokManager.efi" {
> search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root 54A7-D57B
> chainloader (${root})/EFI/ubuntu/MokManager.efi
> }
> ### END /etc/grub.d/25_custom ###
>
>  ### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
> menuentry 'Windows Boot Manager (auf /dev/sdc2)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-efi-54A7-D57B' {
>     insmod part_gpt
>     insmod fat
>     set root='hd2,gpt2'
>     if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
>       search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd2,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd2,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci2,gpt2  54A7-D57B
>     else
>       search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 54A7-D57B
>     fi
>     chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
> }
> set timeout_style=menu
> if [ "${timeout}" = 0 ]; then
>   set timeout=10
> fi
> ### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
>
> ### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
> ### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
>
> ### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
> # This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
> # menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
> # the 'exec tail' line above.
> ### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
>
> ### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
> if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
>   source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
> elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
>   source $prefix/custom.cfg;
> fi
>  ## END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> =============================== sdb2/etc/fstab: ================================
>
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> # /etc/fstab: static file system information.
> #
> # Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
> # device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
> # that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
> #
> # <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
> # / was on /dev/sdb2 during installation
> UUID=1b4c1f8c-da20-43e8-aafe-8726f047c11f /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
> # /home was on /dev/sda3 during installation
> UUID=e365b6b6-cbd2-42f3-84d5-e0fff42416f5 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
> # swap was on /dev/sdb3 during installation
> UUID=24c324b4-3b2e-4d15-8d71-9150d1729d35 none            swap    sw              0       0
> UUID=54A7-D57B    /boot/efi   vfat    defaults    0   1
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> =================== sdb2: Location of files loaded by Grub: ====================
>
>       GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
>
>
> ======================== Unknown MBRs/Boot Sectors/etc: ========================
>
> Unknown BootLoader on sdc2
>
>  00000000  eb 58 90 4d 53 44 4f 53  35 2e 30 00 02 02 fe 19  |.X.MSDOS5.0.....|
>  00000010  02 00 00 00 00 f8 00 00  3f 00 ff 00 00 18 0e 00  |........?.......|
>  00000020  00 20 03 00 01 03 00 00  00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00  |. ..............|
>  00000030  01 00 06 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
>  00000040  80 01 29 7b d5 a7 54 4e  4f 20 4e 41 4d 45 20 20  |..){..TNO NAME  |
>  00000050  20 20 46 41 54 33 32 20  20 20 33 c9 8e d1 bc f4  |  FAT32   3.....|
>  00000060  7b 8e c1 8e d9 bd 00 7c  88 56 40 88 4e 02 8a 56  |{......|.V@.N..V|
>  00000070  40 b4 41 bb aa 55 cd 13  72 10 81 fb 55 aa 75 0a  |@.A..U..r...U.u.|
>  00000080  f6 c1 01 74 05 fe 46 02  eb 2d 8a 56 40 b4 08 cd  |...t..F..-.V@...|
>  00000090  13 73 05 b9 ff ff 8a f1  66 0f b6 c6 40 66 0f b6  |.s......f...@f..|
>  000000a0  d1 80 e2 3f f7 e2 86 cd  c0 ed 06 41 66 0f b7 c9  |...?.......Af...|
>  000000b0  66 f7 e1 66 89 46 f8 83  7e 16 00 75 39 83 7e 2a  |f..f.F..~..u9.~*|
>  000000c0  00 77 33 66 8b 46 1c 66  83 c0 0c bb 00 80 b9 01  |.w3f.F.f........|
>  000000d0  00 e8 2c 00 e9 a8 03 a1  f8 7d 80 c4 7c 8b f0 ac  |..,......}..|...|
>  000000e0  84 c0 74 17 3c ff 74 09  b4 0e bb 07 00 cd 10 eb  |..t.<.t.........|
>  000000f0  ee a1 fa 7d eb e4 a1 7d  80 eb df 98 cd 16 cd 19  |...}...}........|
>  00000100  66 60 80 7e 02 00 0f 84  20 00 66 6a 00 66 50 06  |f`.~.... .fj.fP.|
>  00000110  53 66 68 10 00 01 00 b4  42 8a 56 40 8b f4 cd 13  |Sfh.....B.V@....|
>  00000120  66 58 66 58 66 58 66 58  eb 33 66 3b 46 f8 72 03  |fXfXfXfX.3f;F.r.|
>  00000130  f9 eb 2a 66 33 d2 66 0f  b7 4e 18 66 f7 f1 fe c2  |..*f3.f..N.f....|
>  00000140  8a ca 66 8b d0 66 c1 ea  10 f7 76 1a 86 d6 8a 56  |..f..f....v....V|
>  00000150  40 8a e8 c0 e4 06 0a cc  b8 01 02 cd 13 66 61 0f  |@............fa.|
>  00000160  82 74 ff 81 c3 00 02 66  40 49 75 94 c3 42 4f 4f  |.t.....f@Iu..BOO|
>  00000170  54 4d 47 52 20 20 20 20  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |TMGR    ........|
>  00000180  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
>  *
>  000001a0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 0d 0a 4d 65  |..............Me|
>  000001b0  64 69 65 6e 66 65 68 6c  65 72 ff 0d 0a 4e 65 75  |dienfehler...Neu|
>  000001c0  73 74 61 72 74 3a 20 54  61 73 74 65 20 64 72 81  |start: Taste dr.|
>  000001d0  63 6b 65 6e 0d 0a 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |cken............|
>  000001e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
>  000001f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ac 01 bb 01 00 00 55 aa  |..............U.|
>  00000200
>
>
> =============================== StdErr Messages: ===============================
>
> cat: /tmp/BootInfo-LqSMQMp2/Tmp_Log: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
> ```

Did anyone experience a similar situation or has any tips on how to resolve this?

Comment: But why did the setup work until sunday and suddenly stopped? Have there been any updates recently, that could have caused this?

Comment: We see only a part of your boot info summary (question length is limited), better to add link to pastebin. From what I can see so far it looks like you mixed up boot modes (UEFI/legacy). Do not boot in legacy mode, boot in UEFI mode. Best do disable CSM in UEFI-settings.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. I created a link to Pastebin (hope that works). Maybe you see any additional information in there. If not. I'll try to do as you advised later, when I am back at the Windows/Linux PC.

Comment: After yesterdays update it started to work again. O.o